# Length of strings in unicode are different

Tags: php, unicode

How come the length of the following strings is different although the number of characters in the strings are the same

```
echo strlen("馐 馑 馒 馓 馔 馕 首 馗 馘")."<BR>";
echo strlen("Ɛ Ƒ ƒ Ɠ Ɣ ƕ Ɩ Ɨ Ƙ")."<BR>";
```

Outputs

```
35
26
```

Comment: @stereofrog  what about the for example the letter 'a' . when we strlen its unicode value we get 1

Comment: This is how it worked for me, example: echo mb_strlen("αβγδε",mb_detect_encoding("αβγδε")); it outputs 5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first batch of characters take up three bytes each, because they're way down in the 39-thousand-ish character list, whereas the second group only take two bytes each, being around 400. (The number of bytes/octets required per character are discussed in the [UTF-8 wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).)

strlen counts the number of bytes taken by the string, which gives such odd results in Unicode.

Comment: can you explain further how it they take three and two bytes?

Comment: I'm not an expert on how Unicode works, but basically each character is a variable number of bytes, and the most significant bit of each byte tells the reader the length, or something. I just Googled for Unicode when I needed to find out.

Comment: what about the for example the letter 'a' . when we strlen its unicode value we get 1

Comment: `a` has position 129, which in binary is `01000001`, thus one byte.
`é` has position 233, which is `11101001`, however in UTF-8 the last bit is "reserved", so it is encoded as `11000011 10101001`, making two bytes (this is why you occasionally see `é` replaced by `Ã©`, as those two characters are the ASCII characters for the two bytes). I can't remember the exact significance of the bits or the method of encoding, but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 9):

I am no PHP expert but it seems that `strlen` it counts bytes... there is [`mb_strlen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) which counts characters...

**EDIT** - for further reference on how multi-byte encoding works see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-width_encoding and esp. UTF8 see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 and

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's counting the number of *bytes* in the encoding being used. For example, it looks like the second string is taking two bytes per non-space character, whereas the first string is taking three bytes per non-space character. I would expect:

```
echo strlen("A B C D E F G H I")
```

to print out 17 - a single byte per ASCII character.

My guess it that this is all using the UTF-8 encoding - which would certainly be in-line with the varying width of representation.

Answer (score 1):

Use [mb_strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php), it count characters in provided encoding, not bytes as `strlen`

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post on php.net/strlen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php#90486), PHP interprets all strings passed to `strlen` as ASCII.