# Counting Tamil string length php

Tags: php, tamil

I was developing a site for my customer which uses both English and Tamil languages.

I need to find the length of a Tamil string to generate stripped content.

Can anyone suggest me how to find the length of a Tamil string and substr function for Tamil language.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537556/length-of-strings-in-unicode-are-different

Comment: some one mark it as duplicate

Answer (score 4):

Use \pL\pM to count Tamil characters length. It will gives exact count of Tamil letters

```
$word = "மொழிகளும்";
$regex = "/\pL\pM*|./u";//Unicode letter & Unicode Mark
preg_match_all($regex, $word, $out);
echo count($out[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Better use [mb_strlen()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mb-strlen.php). That should take special chars into account. There are multi-byte equivalents of almost all string functions. If this still does not work, try it with the correct encoding.